# Using the Planning Comptonents Visualizer to Control the hardware

Tags: rviz, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use the Planning Components Visualizer to directly control the arm?

Or is there something else that exists with similar functionality?

I want to be able to move around the physical arm rather than just the visualization of one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11286/using-the-planning-comptonents-visualizer-to-control-the-hardware/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2011-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The arm navigation warehouse viewer does exactly this and a lot more.  The tutorial on it is a little out of date, but still should largely work: http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Warehouse%20Viewer .

Make sure to update your debs as we just released the arm_navigation_experimental stack with some important bug fixes.

Look particularly at Section 4.2.3 . This script now creates a planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_<your_robot_name>.launch file in your auto-generated arm navigation application directory which you can run directly.  Running alongside a running system should just involve filling out topics for your controllers and selecting the "Use Robot Data" flag.

We'll be updating the tutorial soon.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2011-11-29**:
I'm looking forward for updated tutorial... :-)